# Is is possible to pass a helper as an argument to a handlebars partial?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Suppose I have a helper that returns a data object. I'd like to pass that data object to a partial like so:

`{{> somePartial data=someHelper}}`

Is something like this possible?

I should mention this is in Node using the `express-handlebars` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do use a Handlebars [subexpression](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) to do this. Subexpressions are delimited by parentheses:

```
{{> somePartial data=(someHelper)}}
```

If you wanted to pass an argument to your helper you would do so in the following way:

```
{{> somePartial data=(someHelper 'arg')}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I guess it pays to RTFM!